# Error: Data truncated for column 'posted' at row 1 - Date Field

Tags: django, django-models

I am receiving a the following error when I try to save a post from the admin app. All the pages work correctly in the browser. I found several posts regarding this error and it seems in those cases the field has more data than the max_length has allowed. I do not understand my case since the field it is complaining about is a date field. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Error:
Data truncated for column 'posted' at row 1

Link to the traceback:
http://dpaste.com/1429237/

My Model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug }


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, db_index=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'view_blog_category', None, { 'slug': self.slug }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a DateField instead of DatetimeField?

Comment: Thanks for the response. No I have not tried that. God willing I will try that, then I'll update you. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ok so that worked. I created a new db, changed the field, then synced,  and everything works. I guess it would be nice to understand what the issue was. I am not sure if dropping the db was necessary, it was only doable since this was a practice app. Obviously that is not practical in real scenario. I have a question, if I had changed the field and synced would it have updated the change in the db? Keep in mind I am just learning dynamic development. Been stuck doing static for awhile. Thanks:)